# Wiremock - how to hook into wiremock running on docker

Tags: java, docker, api, junit5, wiremock

I have inherited an existing API component testing framework (Java) which works by firing up a docker with the API running in it, and a second with a Wiremock server which is mocking the end data-source. The tests are written with JUnit5.

The dockers are fired up using Gradle composeUp, not specifically in my code. The only setup in my test code is to declare the port number:

```
WireMock.configureFor("localhost", 8080);
```

This all works fine, the Wiremock server picks up the requests from the API using mapping files, without issue, and returns the appropriate mock response.

However, this approach means I have very little visibility of what's happening between the API and the mock, so it's really hard to nail down if they' are both doing what I think they're doing. For some edge cases, I really need to be able to have more info about how the two are interacting.

Because I don't have a *declared instance* of a Wiremock, I can't use it's methods like getAllServeEvents() and isRunning() etc, which would be the ideal option.

Is there any way I can hook into this Wiremock server so I have have access to its methods and can gather some intel around what it's doing, as I would if I were just mocking in memory. I seem to remember that in JUnit4, you had to explicitly declare the Wiremock (WiremockRule?) which would give me a referent like:

```
List<ServeEvent> allServeEvents = <mock>.getAllServeEvents();
```

but I'm at the limit of my expertise at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've set WireMock's static DSL up with the `configureFor` call you can actually call `WireMock.getAllServeEvents()` and this will pull everything currently in the WireMock server's request journal.

You can also pull the log via the API by doing a `GET` to `http://localhost:8080/__admin/requests`.

Finally, if you're able to change the startup command line for the Docker container to add `--verbose` to the WireMock command it'll start logging every request/response to the container's stdout so you can tail it using the Docker CLI.